# IIS 10 (server 2016) SSL redirect to www. and .se

Tags: ssl, iis, https

I have a site with multiple domainnames and have just implemented an ssl certificate to the site. 
but there is a problem when redirecting the incomming requests.

I want to configure it so all requests should redirect to one singel domainname (https://www.barnensbibliotek.se).

The ssl cert is for *.barnensbibliotek.se and www.barnensbibliotek.se and the other domainnames should just redirect to them regardless if the are http or https

i would like to redirect all other domainnames for barnensbibliotek like: barnensbibliotek.se, barnensbibliotek.com and www.barnensbibliotek.com (.info, .org, .nu, .net) to the https://www.barnensbibliotek.se.

I used this code in the web.config (this code works for www.barnensbibliotek.se but not for the others)

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to https" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" negate="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>         
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Create a new rules for all that you want to redirect to `https://www.barnensbibliotek.se` in front of this rule. There, add a condition to check `{HTTP_HOST}` to match the domains you want to unify, and edit action to redirect to `https://www.barnensbibliotek.se` instead of `{HTTP_HOST}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved widt this code:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="http: to https" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```